# React : how to update states which have both mutable and immutable values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

In Javascript, [string, integer and boolean values are immutable, but objects and arrays are mutable.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M-r8p9ey8U)

How should we update states in React, if states have both types of values?

e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        success: false,
        error: false,
        errorMessages: {}
    };
}
```

Assuming that you need to upgdate all of the properties (`success`, `error`, `errorMessages`) at once, what would be best way to achieve it?

At least I'm sure that `errorMessages` shouldn't be updated directly, because it's mutable by nature, but what about the rest of them?

I tried something like the following, but this ends up in a wrong result.

```
const errorMessages = {
    ...this.state,
    "errorMessages": error.response.data,
};

this.setState({
    errorMessages,
    success: false,
    error: true,
});

//The errorMessages property will have "success" and "error" property in it
```

Comment: Value being mutable or immutable doesn't have anything to do with states in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you supply a new value for `errorMessages`, React will update the state correctly. You're not mutating state directly here, you're just providing a new value for the field, and React will do the necessary mutation:

```
this.setState({
   errorMessages: error.response.data
   success: false,
   error: true,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So assuming your state is originally this

```
this.state = {
    success: false,
    error: false,
    errorMessages: {}
};
```

And then you create a new object for your `errorMessages` like this

```
const errorMessages = {
    ...this.state,
    "errorMessages": error.response.data,
};

this.setState({
    errorMessages,
    success: false,
    error: true,
});
```

Then, your next state will kinda look like this, and I am unsure if this is what you want

```
{
   errorMesages: {
     success: false,
     error: true,
     errorMessages: {
       // content of the error.response.data
     }
   },
   success: false,
   error: true
}
```

You probably wanted to assign the new state directly, which is in fact the `errorMessages` const you created, you are just over doing it ;)

The reason why this is so, is because when adding a variable to an object without a value, but just by name, javascript will automatically name the label the same as the variable, eg:

```js
const a = 10;
const b = {
  a
};

// result in: { a: 10 };
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to update state:

```
this.setState({
    success: !this.state.success,
    error: !this.state.error,
    errorMessages: delete this.state.id // if id were a prop in errorMessages
})

this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    success: !prevState.success,
    error: !prevState.error,
    errorMessages
  }
});

this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    success: !prevState.success,
    error: !prevState.error,
    errorMessages
  }
}, () => { // some callback function to execute after setState completes })
```

Comment: I should state though, that you should use mutators instead. So, instead of deleting the prop directly from state, you should copy the object into a variable, then delete the prop, then setState to the copied object. Not a very efficient method though.